# DomPopupSourceFactory provider error when using material-dropdown-select

Tags: dart, angular-dart, material-components

I am trying to use material dropdown select but I am getting this error:

```
EXCEPTION: No provider found for DomPopupSourceFactory.
```

The materialDirectives is added to the directives list, the html call is simple:

```
<material-dropdown-select></material-dropdown-select>
```

I tried the angular_components_example and it worked fine. The problem is with my project. I already tried to clean the .packages and executed the pub get. Nothing worked. I tried some other material components and they worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `materialProviders` to `AppComponent` it should work:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: const <dynamic>[
    CORE_DIRECTIVES,
    materialDirectives,
  ],
  providers: const <dynamic>[
    materialProviders, // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  ],
)
class AppComponent {...}
```

Comment: oh, didn't know that. However, the select is used by a component inside a lib. I will try to add popupBindings to the component providers

Comment: it worked. lol. I list 1 hour at this. I think that the popupBindings in the demo should be used within the select demo, so people who scavenger it sees it quicker than I did. Thanks Gunter =]

Comment: I searched a bit for that as well a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

It works in angular_components example because the app-level component includes the necessary `popupBindings` provider.

If you aren't including `materialProviders` in your app, you can use a more specific provider in your components.

Here is the minimum boilerplate required for using `material-dropdown-select`:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/laminate/popup/module.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_select/material_dropdown_select.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-dropdown-select',
  directives: const [
    MaterialDropdownSelectComponent,
  ],
  providers: const [
    popupBindings,
  ],
)
class MyDropdownSelectComponent {}
```